# How can I use BeanUtils copyProperties to copy from boolean to Boolean?

Tags: java, apache-commons-beanutils

BeanUtils copyProperties, out of the box, doesn't seem to handle copying from Boolean object properties to boolean primitive properties.

I figured I could create and register a converter to handle this, but that just didn't seem to work.

So, how can I use BeanUtils to copy the properties from class Source to class Destination where:

```
public class Destination {

    private boolean property;

    public boolean isProperty() {
        return property;
    }

    public void setProperty(boolean property) {
        this.property = property;
    }
}


public class Source{

    private Boolean property;

    public Boolean getProperty() {
        return property;
    }

    public void setProperty(Boolean property) {
        this.property = property;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm stuck on this one as well now.  Plz add an answer 'carrier' if you were able to do it :)

Answer (score 3):

```
try creating both 
/*by default beanutils copyproperties looks for below method if you use either apache or spring flavour of beanutils.
always prefer using apache 1.9.2 ( fixed many bugs) but bit slow compared with spring beanutils.*/
 public Boolean getProperty() {
        return property;
    }
//which is used by some frameworks 
 public Boolean isProperty() {
        return property;
    }
```

Comment: need to use converter when we use apache beanutils like if we have 
        ConvertUtils.register(new DateConverter(null), java.util.Date.class);

Answer (score 0):

It is actually vice-versa:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Source d = new Source();
    d.setProperty(Boolean.TRUE);
    BeanMap beanMap = new BeanMap(d);

    Destination s = new Destination();
    BeanUtils.populate(s, beanMap);
    System.out.println("s.getProperty()=" + s.isProperty());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Destination {
    private boolean property;

    // code getProperty() instead
    public boolean isProperty() {
        return property;
    }

    public void setProperty(boolean property) {
        this.property = property;
    }
}
```